# JavaFx TableView border css

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have 2 questions to javafx css....
I need a table with freezed first column. As I found on SO it is not suppported directly, so I added a new Tableview with only one column that is bound with the second tableview.

Anyway.

1 Question: Having to tableviews I got this "table-view-border-lines" which I want to get rid of, so that it looks like one table. Is it possible?

2 Question: clicking on tableview I am getting also a "blue-focus-border". I'd like to get rig of the focus border completely. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by frozen first column. What would happen when you need scrollbars? What happens if one table scrolls and the other doesn't? Why can't you have the column in the same table, and have it have a constant value?

Comment: frozen - I need a solution: when scrolling right the first column(with numbers) is always visible. If is is only one table the whole table "scroll's". I need a solution when the first column is bound to its position. I read it is achievable by creating second tableview.
So scrollbars: scrolling up-down: the scrolbarrs are bound to eachother. Scrolling left-right. The first tableview does not have a scroll bar, the second one works default which is ok